# preg_match(): Unknown modifier ')

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-8

getting the error `ErrorException: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ')' in file C:\wamp\www\abcd\app\Rules\Htmlstring.php on line 35` for below code.

$rules = ['cartTemplate'=>['required',new Htmlstring],];

```
class Htmlstring implements Rule
{
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
      return preg_match('/<(/)?(body|html|head|p|b|strong|a|i|span|div)*>/',$value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unescaped slash inside your regex:

```
/<(/)?(body|html|head|p|b|strong|a|i|span|div)*>/
   ^
   |
This one
```

You can change it this way:

```php
return preg_match('/<(\/)?(body|html|head|p|b|strong|a|i|span|div)*>/', $value);
```

Now it works.